# Merge [clib] and [c-libraries] to [c-library]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

The tags [clib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clib) (8) and [c-libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-libraries) (52) both have neither tag wiki information nor guidance. Looking at the questions tagged, both seem to address problems in the same area: *the* or *a* C library. Therefore I'd suggest to merge them. The singular form, [c-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-library) (which does not currently exist), looks most reasonable to me.

Comment: What's wrong with merging/synonymizing "clib" into "c-libraries"?

Comment: There is nothing particular wrong with the existing [c-libraries]; the singular form looks more appropriate to cover the standard C library as well. But if re-tagging makes a lot of work, the plural form would probably do no harm.